# What is the meaning of "mark" in this (probably archaic) usage?

Tags: meaning, archaicisms

In the script for Stanley Kubrick's film Barry Lyndon, which is set in Europe in the late 1700s, there's a use of the word "mark" that I didn't understand.

---

```
        CAPTAIN GROGAN
Well, if it must be, it must.  For a
young fellow, you are the most
bloodthirsty I ever saw.  No
officer, bearing His Majesty's
commission, can receive a glass of
wine on his nose, without resenting
it -- fight you must, and Best is a
huge, strong fellow.

        RODERICK
He'll give the better mark.  I am
not afraid of him.
```

---

How is the word mark being used above? Is this an archaic use from the 1700s?

Comment: Best is a huge man, he'll give the better mark: he'll make an easier target.

Comment: @Bread: Oh, of course. I can't believe I didn't get that. Thanks.

Comment: "_and is it I 
That drive thee from the sportive court, where thou 
Wast shot at with fair eyes, to be the mark 
Of smoky muskets?_" [Shakespeare](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=allswell&keyword1=mark&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mark**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mark)

> importance; prominence; a target

As in:

> "A fellow of no mark nor likelihood" (Shakespeare).
>    "A mounted officer would be a conspicuous mark" (Ambrose Bierce).